# Conditional mean statement

Tags: r, conditional-statements, mean

I have a dataset named `bwght` which contains the variable `cigs` (cigarattes smoked per day)

When I calculate the mean of `cigs` in the dataset `bwght` using:
`mean(bwght$cigs)`, I get a number 2.08.

Only 212 of the 1388 women in the sample smoke (and 1176 does not smoke):

`summary(bwght$cigs>0)` gives the result:

```
Mode      FALSE    TRUE    NA's 
logical    1176     212       0
```

I'm asked to find the average of `cigs` among the women who smoke (the 212).

I'm having a hard time finding the right syntax for excluding the non smokers = 0
I have tried:

- `mean(bwght$cigs| bwght$cigs>0)`
- `mean(bwght$cigs>0 | bwght$cigs=TRUE)`
- `if (bwght$cigs > 0){
  sum(bwght$cigs)
  }`
- `x <-as.numeric(bwght$cigs, rm="0");
  mean(x)`

But nothing seems to work!  Can anyone please help me??

Comment: I retagged your question as an R question, which will help it get some additional attention. I'll write up an answer for you right now.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you want to exclude the non-smokers, you have a few options.  The easiest is probably this:

```
mean(bwght[bwght$cigs>0,"cigs"])
```

With a data frame, the first variable is the row and the next is the column. So, you can subset using `dataframe[1,2]` to get the first row, second column. You can also use logic in the row selection. By using `bwght$cigs>0` as the first element, you are subsetting to only have the rows where `cigs` is not zero.

Your other ones didn't work for the following reasons:

```
mean(bwght$cigs| bwght$cigs>0)
```

This is effectively a logical comparison. You're asking for the TRUE / FALSE result of `bwght$cigs OR bwght$cigs>0`, and then taking the mean on it. I'm not totally sure,  but I think R can't even take data typed as logical for the `mean()` function.

```
mean(bwght$cigs>0 | bwght$cigs=TRUE)
```

Same problem. You use the `|` sign, which returns a logical, and R is trying to take the mean of logicals.

```
if(bwght$cigs > 0){sum(bwght$cigs)}
```

By any chance, were you a SAS programmer originally? This looks like how I used to type at first. Basically, `if()` doesn't work the same way in R as it does in SAS. In that example, you are using `bwght$cigs > 0` as the if condition, which won't work because R will only look at the first element of the vector resulting from bwght$cigs > 0. R handles looping differently from SAS - check out functions like lapply, tapply, and so on.

```
x <-as.numeric(bwght$cigs, rm="0")
mean(x)
```

I honestly don't know what this would do. It might work if `rm="0"` didn't have quotes...?

Answer (score 3):

```
mean(bwght[bwght$cigs>0,"cigs"])
```

I found the statement failed, returning "argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA"

Converting to matrix solved this:

```
mean(data.matrix(bwght[bwght$cigs>0,"cigs"]))
```