# Compute the mean in R subject to conditions

Tags: r

I tried following the advice on this post ([Conditional mean statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12555179/conditional-mean-statement)), however it did not seem to work for me. I get the error `Error in x[j] : only 0's may be mixed with negative subscripts`.

So I have a database called `data` with a few different columns and many rows. There is one indicator column, `z`, which takes value `0` or `1`. I want to compute the mean of the column `base` if `z` depending on whether `z=0` or `z=1`. So I have used the following line of code:

```
mean(data[data$z==1, data$base], na.rm = TRUE)
```

But as mentioned, I get the error `Error in x[j] : only 0's may be mixed with negative subscripts`. I'm unsure why I am getting this error, or what I could/should do instead. I do not actually understand the error.

Thanks.

Comment: Try: `mean(data$base[data$z==1], na.rm = TRUE)` or `mean(data[data$z==1, "base"], na.rm = TRUE)`

Comment: Thanks! Yes, that worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Using the comment by GKi worked and solved my problem. In the end I used

```
mean(data$base[data$z==1], na.rm = TRUE)
```